# System error: exec: "deployment": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: kubernetes

I following the example exactly, [http://kubernetes.io/docs/hellonode/,]

after I run [kubectl run hello-node --image=gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/hello-node:v1 --port=8080
deployment "hello-node" created] . the pod doesnot run ok, I get CrashLoopBackOff status.I have no  deployment exec,

any comment is appreciated.

Nobert

==========================================

```
norbert688@kubernete-codelab-1264:~/hellonode$ kubectl  get pods
NAME                          READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
hello-node-2129762707-hte0f   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   5          6m





norbert688@kubernete-codelab-1264:~/hellonode$ kubectl  describe  pod  hello
Name:           hello-node-2129762707-hte0f
Namespace:      default
Node:           gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf/10.140.0.3
Start Time:     Mon, 28 Mar 2016 20:07:53 +0800
Labels:         pod-template-hash=2129762707,run=hello-node
Status:         Running
IP:             10.16.2.3
Controllers:    ReplicaSet/hello-node-2129762707
Containers:
  hello-node:
    Container ID:       docker://dfae3b1e068a5b0e89b1791f1acac56148fc649ea5894d36575ce3cd46a2ae3d
    Image:              gcr.io/kubernete-codelab-1264/hello-node:v1
    Image ID:           docker://1fab5e6a9ef21db5518db9bcfbafa52799c38609738f5b3e1c4bb875225b5d61
    Port:               8080/TCP
    Args:
      deployment
      hello-node
      created
    QoS Tier:
      cpu:      Burstable
      memory:   BestEffort
    Requests:
      cpu:              100m
    State:              Waiting
      Reason:           CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:         Terminated
      Reason:           ContainerCannotRun
      Message:          [8] System error: exec: "deployment": executable file not found in $PATH
      Exit Code:        -1
      Started:          Mon, 28 Mar 2016 20:14:16 +0800
      Finished:         Mon, 28 Mar 2016 20:14:16 +0800
    Ready:              False
    Restart Count:      6
    Environment Variables:
Conditions:
  Type          Status
  Ready         False 
Volumes:
  default-token-k3zl5:
    Type:       Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName: default-token-k3zl5
Events:
  FirstSeen     LastSeen        Count   From                                            SubobjectPath                   Type            Reason          Message
  ---------     --------        -----   ----                                            -------------                   --------        ------          -------
  6m            6m              1       {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}    spec.containers{hello-node}     Normal          Pulling         pulling image "gcr.io/kubernete-codelab-1264/hello-node:v1"
  6m            6m              1       {default-scheduler }                                                            Normal          Scheduled       Successfully assigned hello-node-2129762707-hte0f to gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf
  6m            6m              1       {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}    spec.containers{hello-node}     Normal          Created         Created container with docker id 41c8fde8f94b
  6m            6m              1       {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}    spec.containers{hello-node}     Warning         Failed          Failed to start container with docker id 41c8fde8f94b with error: API error (500): Cannot start container 41c8fde8f94bee697e3f1a3af88e6b347f5b850d9a6a406a5c2e25375e48c87a: [8] System error: exec: "deployment": executable file not found in $PATH

  6m    6m      1       {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}            Warning FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "hello-node" with RunContainerError: "runContainer: API error (500): Cannot start container 41c8fde8f94bee697e3f1a3af88e6b347f5b850d9a6a406a5c2e25375e48c87a: [8] System error: exec: \"deployment\": executable file not found in $PATH\n"

  6m    6m      1       {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}    spec.containers{hello-node}     Normal  Created Created container with docker id a99c8dc5cc8a
  6m    6m      1       {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}    spec.containers{hello-node}     Warning Failed  Failed to start container with docker id a99c8dc5cc8a with error: API error (500): Cannot start container a99c8dc5cc8a884d35f7c69e9e1ba91643f9e9ef8815b95f80aabdf9995a6608: [8] System error: exec: "deployment": executable file not found in $PATH

  6m    6m      1       {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}            Warning FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "hello-node" with RunContainerError: "runContainer: API error (500): Cannot start container a99c8dc5cc8a884d35f7c69e9e1ba91643f9e9ef8815b95f80aabdf9995a6608: [8] System error: exec: \"deployment\": executable file not found in $PATH\n"

  6m    6m      1       {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}    spec.containers{hello-node}     Normal  Pulled          Successfully pulled image "gcr.io/kubernete-codelab-1264/hello-node:v1"
  6m    6m      1       {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}                                    Warning FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "hello-node" with RunContainerError: "runContainer: API error (500): Cannot start container 977b07a9e5dea5256de4e600d6071e3ac5cc6e9a344cb5354851aab587bff952: [8] System error: exec: \"deployment\": executable file not found in $PATH\n"

  6m    6m      1       {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}    spec.containers{hello-node}     Normal  Created Created container with docker id 977b07a9e5de
  6m    6m      1       {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}    spec.containers{hello-node}     Warning Failed  Failed to start container with docker id 977b07a9e5de with error: API error (500): Cannot start container 977b07a9e5dea5256de4e600d6071e3ac5cc6e9a344cb5354851aab587bff952: [8] System error: exec: "deployment": executable file not found in $PATH

  5m    5m      1       {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}            Warning FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "hello-node" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 20s restarting failed container=hello-node pod=hello-node-2129762707-hte0f_default(b300b749-f4dd-11e5-83ee-42010af0000e)"

  5m    5m      1       {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}    spec.containers{hello-node}     Normal  Created Created container with docker id f8ad177306bc
  5m    5m      1       {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}    spec.containers{hello-node}     Warning Failed  Failed to start container with docker id f8ad177306bc with error: API error (500): Cannot start container f8ad177306bc6154498befbbc876ee4b2334d3842f269f4579f762434effe33a: [8] System error: exec: "deployment": executable file not found in $PATH

  5m    5m      1       {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}            Warning FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "hello-node" with RunContainerError: "runContainer: API error (500): Cannot start container f8ad177306bc6154498befbbc876ee4b2334d3842f269f4579f762434effe33a: [8] System error: exec: \"deployment\": executable file not found in $PATH\n"

  5m    4m      3       {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}            Warning FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "hello-node" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 40s restarting failed container=hello-node pod=hello-node-2129762707-hte0f_default(b300b749-f4dd-11e5-83ee-42010af0000e)"

  4m    4m      1       {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}            Warning FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "hello-node" with RunContainerError: "runContainer: API error (500): Cannot start container d9218f5385cb020c752c9e78e3eda87f04fa0428cba92d14a1a73c93a01c8d5b: [8] System error: exec: \"deployment\": executable file not found in $PATH\n"

  4m    4m      1       {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}    spec.containers{hello-node}     Normal  Created Created container with docker id d9218f5385cb
  4m    4m      1       {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}    spec.containers{hello-node}     Warning Failed  Failed to start container with docker id d9218f5385cb with error: API error (500): Cannot start container d9218f5385cb020c752c9e78e3eda87f04fa0428cba92d14a1a73c93a01c8d5b: [8] System error: exec: "deployment": executable file not found in $PATH

  4m    3m      7       {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}            Warning FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "hello-node" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 1m20s restarting failed container=hello-node pod=hello-node-2129762707-hte0f_default(b300b749-f4dd-11e5-83ee-42010af0000e)"

  3m    3m      1       {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}            Warning FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "hello-node" with RunContainerError: "runContainer: API error (500): Cannot start container 7c3c680f18c4cb7fa0fd02f538dcbf2e8f8ba94661fe2703c2fb42ed0c908f59: [8] System error: exec: \"deployment\": executable file not found in $PATH\n"

  3m    3m      1       {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}    spec.containers{hello-node}     Warning Failed  Failed to start container with docker id 7c3c680f18c4 with error: API error (500): Cannot start container 7c3c680f18c4cb7fa0fd02f538dcbf2e8f8ba94661fe2703c2fb42ed0c908f59: [8] System error: exec: "deployment": executable file not found in $PATH

  3m    3m      1       {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}    spec.containers{hello-node}     Normal  Created         Created container with docker id 7c3c680f18c4
  2m    40s     12      {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}                                    Warning FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "hello-node" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 2m40s restarting failed container=hello-node pod=hello-node-2129762707-hte0f_default(b300b749-f4dd-11e5-83ee-42010af0000e)"

  26s   26s     1       {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}    spec.containers{hello-node}     Warning Failed  Failed to start container with docker id dfae3b1e068a with error: API error (500): Cannot start container dfae3b1e068a5b0e89b1791f1acac56148fc649ea5894d36575ce3cd46a2ae3d: [8] System error: exec: "deployment": executable file not found in $PATH

  26s   26s     1       {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}    spec.containers{hello-node}     Normal  Created         Created container with docker id dfae3b1e068a
  6m    26s     6       {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}    spec.containers{hello-node}     Normal  Pulled          Container image "gcr.io/kubernete-codelab-1264/hello-node:v1" already present on machine
  3m    14s     3       {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}                                    Warning FailedSync      (events with common reason combined)
  5m    3s      26      {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}    spec.containers{hello-node}     Warning BackOff         Back-off restarting failed docker container
  3s    3s      1       {kubelet gke-hello-world-16359f5d-node-zkpf}                                    Warning FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "hello-node" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=hello-node pod=hello-node-2129762707-hte0f_default(b300b749-f4dd-11e5-83ee-42010af0000e)"
```

==========================================

Comment: I made the same mistake going through the kubernetes walkthrough here: http://kubernetes.io/docs/hellonode/ .  Thanks for posting the question.

Comment: Me too made mistake while going through the kubernetes hello world walkthrough docs, Thank you very much for posting question.

Comment: You know what, I did the same and scratched my head for an hour or so finding what is wrong. Only after further debugging (`kubectl describe pods <podname>`) was I able to figure out the problem. I think the guys at Kubernetes need to change the font in their docs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> after I run [kubectl run hello-node --image=gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/hello-node:v1 --port=8080 deployment "hello-node" created]

Do you mean your run `kubectl run hello-node --image=gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/hello-node:v1 --port=8080 deployment "hello-node" created`?

If this is the case, then there is no surprise since `deployment` is not an executable in your PATH.

Comment: yeah,  later, I will look how to  create  [deployment]. thank you

Comment: @norbert you should run `kubectl run hello-node --image=gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/hello-node:v1 --port=8080`

Comment: yeah , it should  run [kubectl run hello-node --image=gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/hello-node:v1 --port=8080 ].